# Position absolute div obeying body margin

Tags: absolute

I have a position absolute div in the body of an html file. I want it to obey the body-margins. Find my code at http://jsfiddle.net/vHApr.
The following is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #222;
    font: 11px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    min-width: 1080px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
div.test{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:55px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test">
TEST
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IF you are willing to use jquery then you can apply the margins from the body to the div on page load

Comment: I want to add right margin to the position absolute div without using right:50px as you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/cNV4L/ (which is in the bottom)

Comment: Add `position:relative` for `body`, then the absolute ancestor element will be aligned to that element. And btw., -1 for the _“It is urgent”_ – no one cares.

Comment: @CBroe, if you have given this as an answer, I would have chosen it as the accepted answer. Thank you CBroe... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position:relative` for `body` – then the absolute descendant element will be aligned to the edges of body, and not to the viewport (which happens for absolutely positioned elements with no positioned ancestors).

Comment: Real magic! Thank you! You never know what else can `position:relative` do

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div.test{
position:absolute;

}
```

Updated  jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vHApr/3/